# How to create a difference between columns in Matrix regardless of whether the periods are consecutive or not

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is data set:
[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5BP.png)

And this is the output table:
[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu6EM.png)

This tables be accomplished by creating a matrix with the following options:

Rows = Type
Columns Year & Period
Values: sum(value)

In order need to create the column (diff1) that shows the difference between each individual column and the previous one, I did these steps

1. I created an index column here is the data including the index
2. Then using this measure to calculate the difference (adapted from this thread: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-columns-without-hard-coding/m-p/505691#M236099)

```
Diff1 = 
VAR currIndex = MAX ( 'Table'[Index] )
VAR currValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] = currIndex),
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Type])
    )
VAR preValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] = currIndex -1),
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Type])
    )
RETURN
    IF ( preValue <> BLANK (),currValue - preValue, "-" )
```

It is almost what I am looking for, however, if we apply a filter on the period, it does not work. This is because they are not consecutive periods ( it works fine if they are consecutive periods).

[Data with filter applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjxFP.png)

I tried to modify the measure to solve this issue by only replacing the "currIndex -1" with "< currIndex":

```
Diff2 = 
VAR currIndex = MAX ( 'Table'[Index] )
VAR currValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] = currIndex),
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Type])
    )
VAR preValue =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Index] ***< currIndex*** ),
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Type])
    )
RETURN
    IF ( preValue <> BLANK (),currValue - preValue, "-" )
```

It actually works fine when the filter is applied:
[diff2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnyw.png)

But it does not work when the filter is removed:
[diff2 results when filter is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxr9g.png)

As you can see, when removing the filter, diff2 takes the difference between the column and all previous columns. Surprisingly, diff1 works right when no filters applied while diff2 works only when filter applied!

So, Is there any way to modify the measure to solve this issue (respecting the filter applied).

Thank you in advance.